# GetDIBits:  bitmap modifications, but crashes out?

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap

GetDIBits:  trying to modify the bitmap, but not sure how to go about it?  I tried lpvBits but it crashes out in the comparison in the "pig" area.  How should I do this?   thx

```
LPVOID lpvBits=NULL;    // pointer to bitmap bits array 
BITMAPINFO bi; 

ZeroMemory(&bi.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)); 
bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 

if (!GetDIBits(dc, m_bmp, 0, 400, lpvBits, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) 
AfxMessageBox("1");


char *pig = (char*)lpvBits;

for (int m=0;m<100;m++)
{
    if (pig[m] > 100)
    {
        pig[m] = 250;
    }
}

SetDIBits( dc, m_bmp, 0, 400, (void *)pig, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS );
```

Comment: lpvBits is null.  It is still null after you call GetDIBits().  Kaboom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx

lpvBits [out]
A pointer to a buffer to receive the bitmap data. If this parameter is NULL, the function passes the dimensions and format of the bitmap to the BITMAPINFO structure pointed to by the lpbi parameter.

example found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969901.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/drawing2bitmap.aspx

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/28469/

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for GetDIBits carefully - the lpvBits pointer is not returned to you - you need to allocate enough memory for the bitmap data you want to fetch, and pass it to GetDIBits to fill it in with image data.